# Understanding arc length calculation

Tags: calculus

My homework asks me to calculate the length of the arc: 
$$y=\int_1^x\sqrt{t^2-1}\,dt,3\le x\le6$$
Here is what I did:

$$y' = \int_a^b\sqrt{t^2-1}$$

$$y'^2=t^2-1 $$

$$1+y'^2 = 1 + t^2 - 1 = t^2$$

$$S=\int_3^6 t^2= \frac{t^3}{3}\Big|_3^6= \frac{6^3}{3} - \frac{3^3}{3} = 72 - 9 = 63$$

This, however, is nowhere close to the answer given. Where have I gone wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S=\int_a^b\sqrt{1+(y'(x))^2}dx$. You calculate $S=\int_a^b(1+(y'(x))^2dx$.

Comment: wow. duh. sometimes I write questions here because I often answer them myself while I'm writing them. Can't believe I didn't catch this one. thanks. will accept when it lets me